# Php gd library How to merge 2 images

Tags: gd

I have an image (src) 300x190
I want to change the size to 300 x 300 by creating an Empty image(dest)300x300 color white 
I have used

```
$dest= imagecreate(300,300);
imagecolorallocate($dest,255,255,255);
imagecopy($src,$dest,0,0,0,0,300,300);
```

but i have a new image (src image and black region).

How to make this image?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your variable naming; `$des` or `$dest`?

In the call to `imagecopy` the `$src` and `$dest` variables are reversed, and the last two parameters (`src_w` and `src_h`) should match the source dimensions, not both be set to `300`.

Fixed code:

```
$dest = imagecreate(300, 300);
imagecolorallocate($dest, 255, 255, 255);
imagecopy($dest, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($src), imagesy($src));
```

Comment: Thank you very much